# How to create a file in sftp server and also need to change the persmission of that file to 511

Tags: java, sftp

I tried using this code:

SshParameters params = new SshParameters(ftpHostname, ftpUsername, ftpPassword);
        SftpConfiguration config = SftpConfiguration.defaultConfiguration();

```
    // create Sftp instance
    Sftp sftp = new Sftp(params,config);

    // capture FTP related events
    sftp.addSftpListener(new DeliverySftpListener());

    // establish secure FTP connection
    sftp.connect();
```

String serverFileName = "FileInServer.txt";

```
    sftp.upload("src/test/java/com/filecreation/testfile/"+fileName+".txt",serverFileName);


    Session session = null;

    JSch jsch=new JSch();        

    Properties configone = new Properties();
    configone.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    configone.put("PreferredAuthentications",password);
    JSch.setConfig(configone);

    session=jsch.getSession("uname", "hostname", port);

    ChannelSftp channel = (ChannelSftp) session.openChannel("sftp");

    if (!channel.isConnected()) 
    channel.connect(5000);
    channel.chmod(511,"/home/abc/FileInServer.txt");
    channel.disconnect();
    session.disconnect();
```

...

Iam getting the following exception :
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: session is down
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.openChannel(Session.java:861)
    at com.visa.apps.comms.delivery.ftp.FileCreation.getListing(FileCreation.java:229)
    at com.visa.apps.comms.delivery.ftp.FileCreation.main(FileCreation.java:44)

Answer (score 2):

You probably forgot to connect to the server. At least there is no session connect in your snippet.

As a sketch it work like

```
Session session = jsch.getSession("uname", "hostname", port);
session.connect();

Channel channel=session.openChannel("sftp");
channel.connect();
ChannelSftp c=(ChannelSftp)channel;
```

Have a look into the [JSch - Example - Sftp.java](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Sftp.java).